# Java Font createFont not working (IOException)

Tags: java, swing, fonts, ioexception

I'm trying to load a custom font I made to a JTable in swing.
This is how I do:

```
private void carregar_font(){
    try {
        URL fontName = getClass().getResource("fonts/open.ttf");
        GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        ge.registerFont(Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File(fontName.toString())));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                } catch(FontFormatException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

This is giving me a IOException. Any suggestion? Thanks

Comment: Could you please post a proper [mcve] and the exact stack trace?

Comment: are you using maven ?

Comment: @Mdkhirulashik , nope

Comment: Application resources will become embedded resources by the time of deployment, so it is wise to start accessing them as if they were, right now.  An [tag:embedded-resource] **must be accessed by *URL* rather than file.**

Answer (score 0):

`getClass().getResource` returns a URL, not a file name.  Passing it directly to `new File` results in an invalid and nonexistent file.

A resource URL is not guaranteed to point to a file.  Use getResourceAsStream and the [other Font.createFont method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#createFont-int-java.io.InputStream-) instead:

```
GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
try (InputStream fontStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("fonts/open.ttf")) {
    ge.registerFont(Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, fontStream));
}
```